# Threads still alive after subscription

Tags: reactive-programming, rx-java2, project-reactor

We are currently migrating from RxJava2 to Project Reactor. To parallize work, we are creating a new Thread via `Schedulers.newThread()` for every parallel HTTP request. We cannot reuse Threads because Spring's SecurityContext is bound to `ThreadLocal`.

Recently we ran into the error, that after some time the JVM runs into OutOfMemory Exceptions, because the created Threads were not disposed leading to thousands of parked Threads, with RxJava the Threads we diposed after a successful HTTP request.

For RxJava the code would be the following, showing no active additional Threads when having a Breakpoint in the last line.

```
Observable<String> deferred = Observable.fromCallable(() -> "1")
            .subscribeOn(io.reactivex.schedulers.Schedulers.newThread());
Observable<String> deferred2 = Observable.fromCallable(() -> "2")
            .subscribeOn(io.reactivex.schedulers.Schedulers.newThread());
System.out.println("obs: " + deferred.blockingSingle());
System.out.println("obs2: " + deferred2.blockingSingle());
```

However for Project Reactor, both Threads are still alive after both stdouts.

```
Mono<String> mono1 = Mono.fromSupplier(() -> "1").subscribeOn(Schedulers.newSingle("single"));
Mono<String> mono2 = Mono.fromSupplier(() -> "1").subscribeOn(Schedulers.newSingle("single"));
System.out.println("Mono1: " + mono1.block());
System.out.println("Mono2: " + mono2.block());
```

A solution for this would be to tear down the scheduler manually in `onFinally`:

```
 Scheduler newSingle = Schedulers.newSingle("single");
 Mono<String> doFinally = Mono.defer(() -> Mono.fromSupplier(() -> "1")).subscribeOn(newSingle).doFinally(s -> {
        newSingle.dispose();
 });
```

However, is this really necessary, or is there a way to establish the same behavior as in RxJava2?

Comment: The RxJava2 documentation mentions `newThread` can lead to `OutOfMemoryError` as well and recommends calling `dispose`... Perhaps there is another structural difference between your two samples? https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/blob/2.x/src/main/java/io/reactivex/schedulers/Schedulers.java#L207

Comment: It seems as RxJava automatically adds a DisposeTask in the case above. `Scheduler.scheduleDirect line: 204`, here a DisposeTask is created which leads to automatic disposal of the worker+executor+scheduler. This is triggered at `blockingSingle()`. However just to clarify: the manual disposal via `doFinally` would be the recommended way to do this?
`